# switch between test and production web service

Tags: c#, webservice-client

I've to implement a web service in c#.
Now they have a test and production web service.
How can I easily switch between them without typing the code twice.

For example

```
var client;

if(test){
    client = WsTest.Client();
}
else{
    client = WsProd.Client();
}
```

With kind regards,

Comment: You can try to use #if DEBUG, or use IoC to inject the proper implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code instead.

```
var client;
#if DEBUG
    client = WsTest.Client();
#else
    client = WsProd.Client();
#endif
```

Assuming that you will run your tests with a debug version and using a release version for you productive code.

If you don't want to have a `WsTest` and a `WsProd` instead I would put all settings in the Web.config. Then you don't have to switch something in your code and configure your webservice via the Web.config. I would prefere this solution because it's more cleaner.